# SwiftUI LazyHGrid rows centering

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an array with 13 items and I'm trying to build `LazyHGrid` with two rows, 7 in the first and 6 in the second row. The second row must be centered inside `LazyHGrid`. Like this:

[image: show image]

I set alignment to GridItem to .center like this:

```
LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible(), alignment: .center)], alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
    ForEach(0..<13) { number in
        Letter(text: self.tray[number], index: number, isTop: true, onChanged: self.letterMoved, onEnded: self.letterDropped)
    }
}
```

But anyway it doesn't help and my result looks like this:

[image: my current result image]

Is it possible to build `LazyHGrid` in this way?

Comment: Grid is a grid. It is not a collection view.

Comment: This article shows some clever ways to get similar effects with a grid: https://swiftui-lab.com/impossible-grids/ (but you may be better off not using a grid!)

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by adding custom offset to each item